# Get "data-something" from an <option> tag contained in <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

I have this HTML

```
<select id="something">
    <option value="1" data-something="true">Something True</option>
    <option value="2" data-something-else="false">Something Else False</option>
</select>
```

And this jQuery snippet with which I'm trying to get the values from `data-*` attributes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('change', 'select#something', function() {
        console.log( $(this).data('something') ); // undefined always
        console.log( $(this).data('something-else') ); // undefined always too
    });
});
```

**How to get `data-*` attribute values with jQuery?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is the select element.

```
console.log($(this).find(":selected").data("something"))
```

Comment: You are too quick man! You'll have to wait 15 minutes so I could accept this answer! Thanks!

Comment: just curious, not strong on jq; is $(this).find(":selected") the same as $(":selected", this) ?

Comment: @dandavis functionally they are the same